# are Socket SSL and HTTP connections safe?

Tags: sockets, security, ssl, encryption

I've worked with AutoTrading Bots for a while, and interacting with several broker's API, I noticed that the biggest part of them require socket SSL or HTTP requests connections.

Now, things have gotten serious, and I'm asking how much these type of connections are safe.

I'm constantly operating with my financial data over this types of connections, and maybe exposing it.

Clearly, I use a VPN (even if I don't know how a VPN can make the difference in this case), and I know that socket SSL connection is encrypted(?), but what for the HTTP? How I could make these type of connections safer? Is it unsafe using Selenium or BeautifulSoup to enter passwords and handle sensitive info?

Examples:

Requests HTTP:

```
requests.post(url, data=payload, verify=True)
```

SSL Socket:

```
def connection(port):
    url = ""
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(30)
    conn = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=url)
    conn.connect((url, port))
```

Comment: SSL is currently called TLS, and TLS 1.3 and even 1.2 is considered a secure standard in the sense that contemporary computing almost certainly won't brute force the packets.   The server's private key can be leaked in which case the packets can probably be decrypted.  Your bigger risk vector is probably either nefarious access to the server side network, or phishing or other attacks on you yourself or someone in the middle.  Agree the VPN isn't really buying you very much in the security department - more adding some obscurity to your source IP

Comment: @erik258 "*SSL is currently called TLS*"- technically, SSL and TLS are different protocols, where SSL is outdated and has been replaced with TLS.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how a VPN can make the difference in this case

A VPN merely establishes a *secure* connection between your computer and a remote network, as-if your computer where physically connected to that network locally.  Any traffic over that connection can't be understood by malicious agents monitoring the connection, only by devices on the same network.

However, while a VPN can secure traffic sent over the open Internet, it won't prevent security breaches by malicious agents that are running on the connected network.  So, use a VPN only to connect to trusted networks.

> I know that socket SSL connection is encrypted(?)

Correct.

> but what for the HTTP?

HTTP by itself is not secure.  But HTTPS, which is just HTTP over a SSL/TLS connection, is perfectly safe *when used properly*.  The majority of the Internet relies on SSL/TLS for its security.

> How I could make these type of connections safer?

SSL/TLS uses peer-to-peer encryption.  In theory, only the two parties who are communicating with each other will know the encryption keys being used, allowing a sender to use the receiver's key to encrypt data that only the receiver can decrypt, and vice versa.

However, if you are not careful, a malicious agent could act as a man-in-the-middle to intercept a SSL/TLS connection.  Meaning, say `A` wants to talk securely to `B`, but `M` is in the middle. `M` would trick `A` into talking to `M`, and trick `B` into talking to `M`.  `M` would pretend to be `B` when talking to `A`, and pretend to be `A` when talking to `B`.  Thus, `M` would gain access to both keys and be able to decrypt all of the data flowing between `A` and `B`.

This is where identity verification comes into play, usually in the form of SSL/TLS certificates.  This way, `A` can validate that it is really talking to `B`, and `B` can validate that it is really talking to `A`. `M` would not have access to either of their certificates needed to fake their identities, so it could not pretend to be either one of them.

If you need secure communications over HTTP, use HTTPS and validate the peer you are communicating with before transmitting anything sensitive.